# Android textview not fit for all the screen

Tags: android, xml

i developed one of application and now am facing problem that it show perfectly in my nexus7 but when i viewing other device screens the text view not fitting
i want all the screen as same as nexus7. its anyone can know the better solution for this please. unfortunately i don't have enough reputation so i cant post any screenshot here this my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/white">

 <RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:paddingBottom="16dp"
 android:paddingLeft="64dp"
 android:paddingRight="64dp"
 android:paddingTop="16dp" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pointer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/point" />

 </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="bottom"
 android:paddingBottom="16dp"
 android:paddingLeft="64dp"
 android:paddingRight="64dp"
 android:paddingTop="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
            android:text="@string/numberusers"
            android:textColor="@color/no_users"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="@string/number"
            android:textColor="@color/no_users"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:paddingBottom="16dp"
     android:paddingLeft="64dp"
     android:paddingRight="64dp"
     android:paddingTop="355dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="false" >

        </ListView>

     </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I m Not Sure But  Remove Relative Layout And Use Linear Layout Its More Better Than Relative

Answer (score 0):

The two textViews that you have in your layout use  android:layout_width="wrap_content".

Use  android:layout_width="match_parent" in the one you want to fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

every children relative layout in your xml has height and width as match_parent. Do you need it? Because if first layout have height as match_arent than it will not leave space for others. Try using "wrap_content" as height for inner relative layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, you have to set the width of the textview as

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

But in my opinion, the hole screen is wrong. Use a LinearLayout (vertical or horizontal) and place there   your first two textviews. And if you want more accuracy use the gravity feature in each text view and of course set a layout_weight for each TextView and weightSum in the LinearLayout.